# Script tag with both external source and body

Tags: javascript, html

I just came across [this sample code](http://unhosted.org/), which has a script tag with both an external source and a body. I assume that this is a clever way to pass some information to the included script.
How does it work?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://unhosted.org/remoteStorage.js">{
      onChange: function(key, oldValue, newValue) {
        if(key=='text') {
          document.getElementById('textfield').value= newValue;
        }
      },
      category: 'documents'
    }</script>
  </head>
```

Comment: I don't think it's as much of a question of how it works than whether this makes a difference in the execution of the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The script contained in the tags will not be evaluated under normal circumstances. What I think is happening in your example is that `remoteStorage.js` is reading the contents itself as it is evaluated. something like this

```
//grab the last script tag in the DOM
//this will always be the one that is currently evaluating during load
var tags = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
var tag = tags[tags.length -1];
//force evaluation of the contents
eval( tag.innerHTML );
```

Although this looks neat in the markup, I, myself would just use a separate script tag and avoid this forced evaluation.

Answer (score 5):

Although browsers are said to ignore the contents of a `script` element when it has a `src` attribute, this just means that they don’t process it the normal way (parse and run as JavaScript code). The contents are still stored in the DOM and can be read by a script. The contents could be just about anything then, not necessarily JavaScript code but any data.

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't work. The [html specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#adef-src-SCRIPT) state that if there's a `src` attribute on the script tag, the contents of the `<script></script>` should be ignored and only the code at the `src` location should be executed.

On the other hand, this would gracefully degrade on browsers that understand javascript, but are not new enough to support external JS code. If any browsers like this exist, who knows, but generally speaking, the onchange code in your snippet should NOT be executed by any decent modern browser.

Comment: If what you say is true, this code makes no sense at all. I somehow doubt that.

Comment: They even have explicit instructions to write the script tag like this: "Inside the <script> ... </script> element, specify 'onChange' and 'category' like below"

Comment: It's true according to the spec. Unfortunately there's far too many bad browsers (*koff*microsoft*koff*) who treat specs as jokes and do their own thing.