# image not sliding in ruby on rails

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery cycle lite plugin for making image slide in rails app. but it is not working. Can anyone tell me what is the problem in my code?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>HealthCare</title>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "EHRMS", :media => "all" %>
<script type='text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'>
$('#mar').cycle({
delay:  2000,
speed:  500,
before: onBefore
}); </script>
</head>
</html>
```

`#mar` is the division with images to slide.

Comment: I notice there is `src='script.js'` in your `script` tag, but it also has code in the body of the tag. Is there a reason you're including both?

Comment: script.js contains the cycle lite plugin

Comment: updated my answer below with a second problem, about that `src` attribute

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript code is running as soon as the page loads, but the page may not be ready to run scripts yet (the DOM may not have been initialized, so the `#mar` element may not exist yet).

Typically you will want to wrap such code in a jQuery `ready()` function, like so:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#mar').cycle({
  delay:  2000,
  speed:  500,
  before: onBefore
  });
});
</script>
```

See the [`ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) documentation for more details.

**Update**

You may also have an additional problem in your code, that your `<script>` tag has both a `src` attribute (`src='script.js'`) but it also has contents between the `<script>...</script>` tags. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676093/script-tag-with-both-external-source-and-body), that's not valid and the body of the `<script>` tags will be ignored. Try breaking that out into a separate `<script>` tag. I've updated my code snippet above with an example of how to do that.

Comment: Anything in the browser console?