# regarding sequence of control flow in html <script>

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html page like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <style>
    </style>
</head>
<body style="height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0">
    <div id="outerParentDiv" style="width:100%; height: 100%;">  
    </div>
    <script src="<script1 - takes very long to download>">
     alert('hi1');
    </script>
    <script src="<script2 - takes very short to download>">
      alert('hi2');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Could I assume the flow to be - download script 1 >> execute alert('hi1')>> download script2 >> execute alert('hi2')
or is it browser specific - if yes, which browsers do what?

Thanks

Comment: Scripts will be _executed_ in the order they are included. It's possible that some browsers will _download_ them in parallel (though of course in this case the second script isn't a separate download).

Comment: So the answer is No for some browsers? Could I get documentation (official) about which browsers would do that? Thanks.

Comment: The answer is "Yes". Note the distinction I made between "execution" and "download"...

Comment: Sorry I edited it but missed to mention. what happens if other one is also downloading script and also contains some execution code inside it.  What would be the sequence in this case? Can I assume - download script 1 >> download script2 >> execute alert?

Comment: If no async or deffer attribute included, script tags whether it is external or internal would be parsed in the order they included. [Scripting HTML 5.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/scripting-1.html#scripting-1)

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307929/javascript-dom-load-events-execution-sequence-and-document-ready

Comment: But they may not be downloaded synchronously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The browser will most likely download both scripts in parallel (unless either script is already cached), but the execution order is guaranteed to be in order. Moreover, the part of the page that is behind the script will not become a part of the script until the script is done loading and executes. This ensures you can safely include libraries in your code, and expect them to be present when the main script gets to run.

As has been noted, you shouldn't use `script` tags with both `src` and own content.

```
<script src = "http://path.to.a.cdn/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function(){
    ...
  })
</script>
```

You can override this behavior by using the `async` or `defer` attributes.

> #### async [html5](/questions/tagged/html5)
>
> Set this Boolean attribute to indicate that the browser should, if possible, execute the script asynchronously. It has no effect on inline scripts (i.e., scripts that don't have the src attribute).
>
> #### defer
>
> This Boolean attribute is set to indicate to a browser that the script is meant to be executed after the document has been parsed. Since this feature hasn't yet been implemented by all other major browsers, authors should not assume that the script’s execution will actually be deferred. Never call `document.write()` from a `defer` script (since Gecko 1.9.2, this will blow away the document). The defer attribute shouldn't be used on scripts that don't have the src attribute.

Neither attribute works in IE before IE 10, so don't rely on the script not executing in order anyways.

Compatibility table: [`async`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=script-async); [`defer`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=script-defer)

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

Answer (score 2):

That is correct. The browser by default interprets the HTML source line-by-line. However, some configurations of browsers may send multiple HTTP Requests simultaneously, (**EDITED**) but the execution order as printed in your code is guaranteed.

Comment: (do you think my answer is worth upvoting, by the way?)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `<script>` with both a `src` attribute and content between `<script ...>` and `</script>`. This can lead to unpredictable results. See [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676093/script-tag-with-both-external-source-and-body?rq=1).

Comment: After 3,426 Reputation, you are still posting an answer like this :P I mean look at the question. Is this what he asked for?

Comment: It's clearly on-point. OP is asking in what order scripts will execute. The answer is: if OP does it the way it's presented in the question, who knows? The `alert`s may not execute at all, depending on particularities of the browser.

Comment: Oh sorry, It seemed like you are telling the OP the right way to write the script tag. *"Don't use <script> with both a src attribute and content between <script ...> and </script>. This can lead to unpredictable results."*