# Send variable to PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

In a WordPress post I'm trying to send data to a PHP file stored in the root folder of my website with this code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
console.log('hi');
var cen = document.getElementById("centro").value;
$.ajax({
        url: 'centroUser.php', 
        type: "POST",
        data: { 'cen': cen },
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
}); 
</script>
```

**centroUser.php:**

```
<?php
   $uid = $_POST['cen'];
   echo($uid);   
?>
```

The problem is that I can't get it to work, the variable `$uid` doesn't get echoed and even the `console.log('hi')` doesn't get called. I'm new to AJAX so I don't really know what I'm doing wrong, I have tried looking for other answers but I couldn't find something that worked.

Comment: Whats `document.getElementById("centro").value` point to?

Comment: Try to wrap your code in a seperate `script` tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Script tag with both external source and body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676093/script-tag-with-both-external-source-and-body)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `<script>` tag has a `src` and a body.

Try:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

console.log('hi');
var cen = document.getElementById("centro").value;
$.ajax({
        url: 'centroUser.php', 
        type: "POST",
        data: { 'cen': cen },
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
}); 
</script>
```

If the src has a URI value, user agents must ignore the element's contents and retrieve the script via the URI - [see here](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/scripts.html#edef-SCRIPT).

Comment: Yes, thanks that was the problem, just a stupid error