# get a function value in java script from html page

Tags: javascript, html

hello i am trying to get a function in a script folder to work on an html page

I have this set up html

```
<script src="add.js">

txt = document.createElement('p')
document.body.appendChild(txt)
txt.innerHTML = add(2);


</script>
```

and script file function

```
function add(a){
return a+a
}
```

Its not working and im not sure why.
i have tried wrapping the whole statements inside a function and calling that. tried onload in different positions and didnt work.

thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does a script-Tag with src AND content mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528325/what-does-a-script-tag-with-src-and-content-mean). Related: [Script tag with both external source and body](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8676093/4642212).

Comment: its not rendering results on the browser

Comment: because that's not legal script use. Put all your JS _in your .js file_, but remember to load it as `<script async defer src="..."></script>` so that you script only runs _after_ the DOM has finished parsing. Finally, don't use `innerHTML` unless you actually need to (unsafely) inject HTML code. If you just want to set text, use `textContent = ...` instead.

Comment: That first script-tag one is not a dupe, that is something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mike said in the comments you can't write your script that way

Two ways to solve it

1:

```
<script src="add.js"></scirpt>
<script>
    //...Code here
</script>
```

2: preferred:

```
<script>
    txt = document.createElement('p');
    document.body.appendChild(txt);
    txt.innerHTML = add(2);

    function add(a){
        return a+a;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: awesome thank you!

Comment: Global variables are **never** "preferred"

Comment: @charlietfl:  guess you could wrap the whole thing in a function but this is a very simple program.